# Make zsh behave like bash for commands without trailing newline

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

Have a look at the following demo:

```
[user@host ~]$ zsh
user@host:~/ > echo -n test
user@host:~/ > bash
[user@host ~]$ echo -n test
test[user@host ~]$
```

`echo -n` is an example for a command, that doesn't print a trailing newline.
There are many commands like this out there, (curl with json output for example) that I get from coworkers and just want to run without modification.
Unfortunately zsh swallows their output. But bash, which is the defacto standard shell on linux, that all my coworkers use, doesn't.
How can I configure zsh to behave like bash and print the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, *zsh* behaves like the following -- you can check this by invoking the shell with `zsh -f` which doesn't load your custom settings:

```
zsh$ echo -n test
test%
zsh$ echo test
test
zsh$
```

The `%`, printed in inverse video, is signalling that an additional newline was added by the shell in order to prevent the prompt overwriting that line (which seemingly happens in your case).

This is controlled by the option `PROMPT_SP` which is set by default and is explained in the manual (`man zshoptions`) like so:

> Attempt to preserve a partial line (i.e. a line that did not end with a newline) that would otherwise be  covered
> up  by  the command prompt due to the PROMPT_CR option.  This works by outputting some cursor-control characters,
> including a series of spaces, that should make the terminal wrap to the next line when a partial line is  present
> (note that this is only successful if your terminal has automatic margins, which is typical).
>
> When  a  partial  line  is preserved, by default you will see an inverse+bold character at the end of the partial
> line:  a ‘%' for a normal user or a ‘#' for root.  If set, the shell parameter PROMPT_EOL_MARK  can  be  used  to
> customize how the end of partial lines are shown.
>
> NOTE:  if  the  PROMPT_CR  option is not set, enabling this option will have no effect.  This option is on by de‐
> fault.

So, long story short, somewhere in your configuration files (usual suspects are `~/.zshrc` and `/etc/zsh/zshrc`, for a complete list see the manual on *STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES*) this option is getting unset. So either find that offending line or reset the option manually:

```
setopt PROMPT_SP
```

Comment: I didn't find that option anywhere in my config. But i'm using a zshrc that I created some 20 years ago and have never looked at again. Now I'm just adding the `setopt PROMPT_SP` to it somewhere at the bottom. ;)

Comment: @DanielSchmitz: Maybe you are `source`'ing some other (third-party?!) files...

Comment: You are right. I'm using the promptinit plugin in my .zshrc:
`autoload -Uz promptinit; promptinit; prompt suse`. This affects the PROMPT_SP behavior. Thanks for pointing this out!